# CSS files not loading for MVC app on IIS 8.5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have an MVC 5 website set up on a Windows 2012 Server using IIS 8.5. My website loads up but the CSS files are not working. This site works on our other Prod server but when we moved to the new Prod server, none of the css files work. The only difference between the 2 servers is that the new server is a Virtual server.

The website uses Windows Authentication, the setting for "Static Content (Installed)" in IIS is checked. I don't have F12 Developer tools installed so I can't see what's going on but when I put the path to the css files in the address bar, it says it can't open the file.
This was an older version of MVC that was upgraded to MVC 5. The links to the css files are using the standard

```html
<link href="~/Content/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and these links reside in my _layout.cshtml file. I'm not using bundle.config but this should still work.
Does anyone know why these files are not served up?
Thanks

Comment: check browser console is there any error it is showing

Comment: check body of the HTTP response by F12, and check where it's redirecting .. for now you can  try this <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/mycss.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: The Console only shows a 500 error. When I try to load the css file in the address bar on the web server, I get a little more information. It looks like it may be a permission issue. If I can access the site, should I have access to the "Content" and "Scripts" folders?

Comment: Hi @Mannan Bahelim, The code was already using Url.Content before I switched it and that didn't work either. F12 only gives me a 500 error.